# How to add a separator between nav header-actions?

Tags: vmware-clarity

In the documentation, there is an example that looks like this:

[Nav with a separator between header actions.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JONOC.png)

But I can't for the life of me figure out how the separator gets added and none of the code examples on the page show an example of it.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which demo that is from (would be helpful to provide a link to make sure I can see what it is). However, some elements automatically add it instead of it being explicitly defined as a standalone element, such as the first `.header .header-nav .nav-link` element will use the `::before` CSS selector to place that line. If you need to put something explicitly, then you'll have to add it yourself.

Comment: It can be seen in a few places such as https://clarity.design/documentation/navigation and https://clarity.design/documentation/header.

I'm pretty sure that it is supposed to be done automatically and I'm just missing a class or a containing element or something like that, I'm just not sure what it is. It would be helpful if their navbar images were actual examples and not images.

Comment: In the documentation many of them are real examples that you can inspect to see, some are images though.

Comment: Unfortunately, all of the ones I've found with a separator between header actions are images. I would love to see one where it could be inspected. Then I'd know what I'm missing.

Perhaps the separators for the header actions were only in their conceptual mock-ups which is why they are all images and not really in fact included in the css. At which point, those images really need to be updated.

Comment: There are some in these examples here https://clarity.design/documentation/header#types

Comment: It seems like you are confusing header-nav vs header-actions. I'm asking about the separator between header-actions specifically as stated in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

I hade the same problem upon seeing the provided examples. When reading the sources a divider is only defined for **.header-nav** elements (https://github.com/vmware/clarity/blob/master/src/clr-angular/layout/nav/_header.clarity.scss) and not for **.header-actions**.

However you could customize **.header-actions .nav-link** in the following way:

```
@import "../node_modules/@clr/ui/src/utils/components.clarity";
@import 'node_modules/@clr/ui/src/layout/nav/header.clarity';

.header-actions {
    &:last-child {
        & > .nav-link:last-child::after {
          content: none;
        }
      }

      .nav-link {
        &:last-of-type {
          position: relative;
        }

        &::after {
          @include header-section-divider();
          left:auto;
          right:0;
        }

        &:last-of-type::after {
          left: 0;
        }

        &.active:last-of-type::after {
          content: none;
        }
      }   
}
```